# Unit Testing Codeactivity Workflow

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, workflow

I am trying to write a unit test for a CodeActivity Workflow. My test so far is only

```
[TestMethod]
public void BusinessUnitTest()
{
    WorkflowInvoker invoker = new WorkflowInvoker(new DespatchStockOrder());
    invoker.Extensions.Add<ITracingService>(() => tracingService);
    invoker.Extensions.Add<IWorkflowContext>(() => workflowContext);
    invoker.Extensions.Add<IOrganizationServiceFactory>(() => factory);
    IDictionary<string, object> outputs = invoker.Invoke();
}
```

This works fine and runs the workflow. However I get a null referrence when I hit this line in the workflow.

```
// Create the context
IWorkflowContext context = executionContext.GetExtension<IWorkflowContext>();

if (context == null)
{
     throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("Failed to retrieve workflow context.");
}

Entity entity = new Entity(context.PrimaryEntityName) //This line errors with PrimaryEntityName null
{
     Id = context.PrimaryEntityId,
     LogicalName = context.PrimaryEntityName
};
```

My question is how do I get context.PrimaryEntityName witha value in a unit test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are building the context manually then you will need to populate the `PrimaryEntityName` in the `[TestMethod]`. You should probably look further into how your `workflowContext` test object is constructed.

```
[TestMethod]
public void BusinessUnitTest()
{
    workflowContext.PrimaryEntityName = "Entity name";

    WorkflowInvoker invoker = new WorkflowInvoker(new DespatchStockOrder());
    invoker.Extensions.Add<ITracingService>(() => tracingService);
    invoker.Extensions.Add<IWorkflowContext>(() => workflowContext);
    invoker.Extensions.Add<IOrganizationServiceFactory>(() => factory);
    IDictionary<string, object> outputs = invoker.Invoke();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I have tried this, but the PrimaryEntityName is a read only attribute and can not be set like this

Comment: Well how are you constructing whatever `workflowContext` is?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [FakeXrmEasy](https://github.com/jordimontana82/fake-xrm-easy). It's an open source unit testing library I'm maintaining to facilitate unit testing for Dynamics Crm without mocking anything.

You [get a reference to a workflow context](https://github.com/jordimontana82/fake-xrm-easy/blob/101234a90512dd7cbb0f894df642b763c333a9f9/FakeXrmEasy.Tests.Shared/FakeContextTests/FakeContextTestCodeActivities.cs#L108-121) and inject whatever parameters you need, including Primary Entity names and Id's.

But the most common crm messages are already mocked (retrieve multiple requests, CRUD, fetchxml, LINQ, QueryExpressions, and so no...)

Comment: Hi @KingRider, what do you mean? :) if it works with CRM online? It is intended for unit testing so yeah, any .NET app using the OrganizationService, regardless of online or onpremise.

Comment: Jordi: yes crm online.. i need its, said test ok.. please notice me live:sandro.alvares .. thanks